# How to make a FPS more stable?

Tags: three.js

Into the scene adding new objects in real-time and made other calculations. Because of this, it turns unstable FPS noticeable freeze on some frames. If
idle mode get 60 frames per second, when the changes in the scene, he can drop to 40, one frame is drawn for example 100 millisecondsand others to 13 milliseconds

For some calculations using VebVorker, to move the camera apply time factor, but it does not give significant results. What are some other ways to make a FPS more stable?

```
var time=new Date().getTime();
function render(){

time=new Date().getTime()-time;
camera.position.x+=time*0.001;

renderer.render(scene,camera);

time=new Date().getTime()
}
```

Comment: How do your objects look like? Maybe you can raise your FPS by modifying them?!

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding a bunch of new objects, maybe try using object pooling? Pre-allocate all of your objects and bring them in as needed.

http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/object-pool.html

Comment: but how this apply in three.js?